# How to pass $_GET id to modal bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I've this bootstrap button:

`<button type='button' class='btn btn-info btn-xs' data-id='"<?php  echo $row['IdPrenotazione']?>"' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'>Dettaglio</button>`

that open a modal bootstrap.

This is the code of modal:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div id='myModal' class='modal fade' role='dialog'>
  <div class='modal-dialog'>
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class='modal-content'>
      <div class='modal-header'>
        <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal'></button>
         <h5 class='modal-title'>Dettaglio Prenotazioni</h4>
            </div>
                <div class='modal-body'>
                <?php
                $conn1 = odbc_connect($dsn,$user,$pass);
                $query1="SELECT TipoEsame.IdTipoEsame+' - '+TipoEsame.Descrizione tipEsame FROM TipoEsame,DettaglioPrenotazione
                        WHERE TipoEsame.IdTipoEsame=DettaglioPrenotazione.IdTipoEsame
                        AND DettaglioPrenotazione.IdPrenotazione="....

                $result1 = odbc_exec($conn1,$query1);
                $testo="

                while($row1 = odbc_fetch_array($result1))
                    {$testo=$testo."<br>".$row1['tipEsame'];}

                odbc_free_result($result1);
                odbc_close($conn1);

                echo $testo;?>


                </div>
        <div class='modal-footer'>
       <button type='button' class='btn btn-info btn-xs' data-dismiss='modal'>Chiudi</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

query on modal code needs 'IdPrenotazione' from database ($row['IdPrenotazione'])

How to do?
Thanks

Comment: php code has to go inside `<?php echo id; ?>`

Comment: See [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
I would love to help you but this doesn't meet quality standards. Help others reproduce the problem. My main issue is that we do not have the SQL database you are referring to and it makes it difficult to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Also seems like you are trying to run server-side code on the client-side.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible to do it in the way you are doing it. You should try to do it with jQuery and Ajax.

However; `IdPrenotazione` is a value that you must recover form database or is a value that you already have in you html (outside the modal)? If you already have it outside the modal tell me and I help you.

Comment: IdPrenotazione comes from database I got it into html outside modal. Problem is how to pass this value to the part of code of modal window.Modal also have to query database by IdPrenotazione passed ad parameter